# Font family name for Josefin Sans

Tags: fonts, sectsty, fontfamily

What is the font family name for Josefin sans? I know that the font can be set by adding

> \usepackage{josefin}

in the preamble. However, I am trying to change the chapter heading style using the package secsty,

> \usepackage{sectsty}

And there I need to provide the font family name

> \chapterfont{\fontfamily{Font Family Name Goes Here}\selectfont}

Therefore, I need to know the font family name for the josefin font. What is the font family name for the josefin font? Moreover, how to know the font family names for different fonts in general, as in is there a list of some kind?

If there is any alternative method to change the fonts for chapter headings without using the font family  name but using the package name directly, please suggest so. (Note that I intend to use different fonts for the chapter/section headings and the text in the body)

Comment: you can use \sffamily in the \chapterfont command (if the package is loaded).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This is not working. The reason I suppose is that I am using cmbright for the body of the text. Thus, when I am using \sffamily, cmbright is overwriting the josefin package. Any solution for that?

Comment: well then use the family name, you get it with my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{josefin}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\sffamily the family name is \f@family 
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The packages `cmbright` and `josefin` fight each other, because they both define `\sfdefault` and the former also defines `\familydefault` to be `\sfdefault`.

I'm not really sure you want two different sans serif fonts for your document. Anyway, this should do.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\edef\familydefault{\familydefault}
\usepackage{josefin}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\chapterfont{\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

Some text in CM Bright. Also math $a+b=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Look at the picture to see why I'm dubious about the two fonts together.

Comment: Thanks! This code should have worked but I think overleaf does not have support for Josefin at all! Any suggestions?